# Android and Orientationchange

Tags: android, mobile, orientation-changes

I have this bit of jQuery:

```
$('body').bind('orientationchange',function(event){
alert('orientationchange');
})
```

If you change the orientation of your device, it should trigger an alert. Works in iOS. Does not work in Android. Why?

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/esacir

I thought perhaps Android doesn't fire that event on the body so also tried 'window': http://jsbin.com/esacir/3 still no-go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works on Android:

```
window.onorientationchange = function() {
    alert('onorientationchange');
}
```

Try declaring the method as done above.

Comment: It's odd that I can't bind that event via jQuery, though.

Comment: you get the answer. The issue is that android needs the event on the window, rather than body. I just had sloppy syntax when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

As usual with me, it was a syntax problem. The key is that the event has to be attached to the window (for android):

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange',function(event){
alert('orientationchange');
})
```